# jQuery Prev Next plugin enhancement

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to go through elements with previuous and next buttons. Here is
HTML :

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Number 1 item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Number 2 item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Number 3 item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Number 4 item</a></li>   
    </ul>
<input type="button" class="next" value=">" />
<input type="button" class="prev" value="<" />
```

JS :

```
(function(){
    var $lis = $('ul li');
    var index = 0, lastIndex = 0;

    start(); // activate first, add event listeners to buttons

    function next(){
        lastIndex = index;
        if(++index == $lis.length) index = 0; // if next is out of bounds go to first
        $lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
        $lis.eq(lastIndex).removeClass('active');
    };

    function prev(){
        lastIndex = index;
        if(--index < 0) index = ($lis.length - 1); // if prev is less than first to to last
        $lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
        $lis.eq(lastIndex).removeClass('active');
    };
    function start(){
        $lis.eq(0).addClass('active');
        $('.next').click(next);
        $('.prev').click(prev);
    }
})();
```

This plugin works perfect, Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rtmdj/14/)

But I want to extend its functionality. I also want to enable clicking on **list** directly & remember its index.

What I mean is : Say, I reached till item no.3 while clicking on next button, & if I directly click on
`<li><a href="#">Number 1 item</a></li>` (item no:1) then I want to remember my this position as current index & when I click on next button, I should move to item no.2

same thing also goes with previous button.

How can I extend this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function li_click(){
    lastIndex = index;
    index = $(this).index();
    $lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
    $lis.eq(lastIndex).removeClass('active');
}

function start(){
    $lis.eq(0).addClass('active');
    $('.next').click(next);
    $('.prev').click(prev);
    $lis.click(li_click);
}
```

Here is an updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rtmdj/15/

Also it doesn't look like you really need the `lastIndex` variable, you can just remove the `active` class, change the `index`, then add the `active` class to the new `index`:

```
$lis.eq(index).removeClass('active');
index = $(this).index();
$lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
```